# test class code coverage for FOR loop

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

How to do code coverage for below nested  loop

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < invlist.size(); i++){
    for (Integer j = i; j > 0; j--) {
         if (date.valueOf(invlist[j - 1].transDate) < date.valueOf(invlist[j].transDate)){
             invwrapper temp = invlist[j];
             invlist[j] = invlist[j - 1];
             invlist[j - 1] = temp;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are using `invlist` for iteration, populate that list with correct values. You can post complete code and test class to find solution easily.

Comment: Hi @anjali, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Your code I assume looks something like this:

```
public class InvWrapperClass{

    // a data structure that holds a string representing a date
    public class invwrapper{
        public String transDate;
        public invwrapper(String s){transDate = s;}
    }

    // a method that uses the bubble sort algorithm 
    //   to sort dates from latest to earliest
    public static void invWrapperBubbleSort(list<invwrapper> invlist){
        for (Integer i = 0; i < invlist.size(); i++){
            for (Integer j = i; j > 0; j--) {
                 if (date.valueOf(invlist[j - 1].transDate) < date.valueOf(invlist[j].transDate)){
                     invwrapper temp = invlist[j];
                     invlist[j] = invlist[j - 1];
                     invlist[j - 1] = temp;
                 }
            }
        }    
    }

}
```

A test class:

```
@isTest
public class InvWrapperClassTest{

    public static @isTest void runTest(){
        // take a list out of order
        list<String> slist = new list<String>{
            '2017-03-23 21:29:00',
            '2016-03-23 21:29:00',
            '2018-03-23 21:29:00'
        };
        list<InvWrapperClass.invwrapper> invlist = new list<InvWrapperClass.invwrapper>();
        for (String s : slist) invlist.add(new InvWrapperClass.invwrapper(s));

        // sort it
        InvWrapperClass.invWrapperBubbleSort(invlist);

        // assert that it is now in the correct order
        system.assertEquals('2018-03-23 21:29:00',invlist[0].transDate);
        system.assertEquals('2017-03-23 21:29:00',invlist[1].transDate);
        system.assertEquals('2016-03-23 21:29:00',invlist[2].transDate);
    }

}
```

---

You should probably use the comparable interface to sort lists:

```
public class invwrapper implements Comparable{
    public String transDate;
    public invwrapper(String s){transDate = s;}

    // this way you don't need to worry about the sorting algorithm
    //   you just need the comparison rules
    public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
        if (this.transDate == ((invwrapper) compareTo).transDate) return 0;
        else if (this.transDate < ((invwrapper) compareTo).transDate) return 1;
        else return -1;
     }
}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
public class InvWrapperClassTest2{
    // the test is essentially the same since 
    //   it is the same functionality you are testing
    public static @isTest void runTest(){
        list<String> slist = new list<String>{
            '2017-03-23 21:29:00',
            '2016-03-23 21:29:00',
            '2018-03-23 21:29:00'
        };
        list<invwrapper> invlist = new list<invwrapper>();
        for (String s : slist) invlist.add(new invwrapper(s));

        // here the list is sorted with the sort() method 
        //    instead of your bubble sort
        invlist.sort();

        system.assertEquals('2018-03-23 21:29:00',invlist[0].transDate);
        system.assertEquals('2017-03-23 21:29:00',invlist[1].transDate);
        system.assertEquals('2016-03-23 21:29:00',invlist[2].transDate);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmm...where did you get the surrounding context?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I just made it up. I figured it had to be something like that.

Comment: Seems like the whole thing should be scrapped and just replaced with an implementation of `Comparable`.

Comment: Yes, that's probably the best advice. @AdrianLarson OP didn't provide much information though on why they where doing it this way.

Comment: Hence why I closed it. But perhaps your answer will help them. Who knows.

Comment: Yeah, you never know.